# Make background of a div with small image by repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I am wondering if the following is possible to implement or not:

Say, I have an image of size 20x20 px and in my website I have a div of 750x500 px and I want to make the image as background of the whole div. I tried to do it by repeating the image but repeating doesn't work good. Background seems distorted in this case. Is there any other way to do this? I searched on internet but nothing came up.

```
![please check the image][1]
```

[image: please check the image]

Comment: Show us your code, please (relevant CSS and HTML).

Comment: I'd rather see the result and what you want to achieve (as images). What you're describing as wanting to achieve is `background-repeat: repeat`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're asking? http://jsbin.com/xuxeci/1/edit

```
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>

div {
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/20/20);
}
```

By default, the above background image repeats in both the `x` and `y` dimensions. This can be limited by applying `background-repeat-x: no-repeat`, or `background-repeat-y: no-repeat`, or background-repeat: no-repeat`(that last one applying to both`x`and`y`).

Doc for `background-repeat`: http://devdocs.io/css/background-repeat

If you're not wanting to repeat (tile) the image, but instead to stretch it to fill the div, you probably want to choose a larger image (larger than 20 by 20 pixels, to avoid pixelation), and do this: http://jsbin.com/xuxeci/2/edit

```
div {
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/2000/2000);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Doc for `background-size`: http://devdocs.io/css/background-size
Doc for `background-position`: http://devdocs.io/css/background-position

You've added a screenshot, and you asked why you're seeing a grid pattern. That's because you're tiling an asymmetrical image (the edges don't match). If you want the background "smooth" (as you described), why not just use a background color? You could name a color (like `gray`) or use a hex-code: http://jsbin.com/picep/1/edit

```
<body>
  <div></div>
```

```
div {
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #5e5e5e; /* One of many hex-code combinations for a medium grey. */
}
```

Comment: background-size: contain might also be a viable option. If using it, disable repeat.

Comment: please check the image I just uploaded

Comment: I think @user1478137 is looking for `background-size: cover` setting.